# adding data to a 2d array in a methodical manner

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, 2d

i have the need to create a 2 d array. in that array there are strings, with ID., resistance values, and a date,

These are to be entered each time, the array size is to be 7x16 for all the data i require,

how can i prompt my user for entry of the code without big long entries in code? i am reading my c# books but im weak on loops, can someone point me to a for of loop that can assist in my skills up on this,

any assistance greatly welcomed, steven

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;   // Has to be included, not in most docs!
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class CellDetails
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter value for Cell ID, Sample, Write/TX, Depass, Discharge Date and Discharge load");
        String[,] CellDetailArray = new String[7, 16];

        // Sets the element at index 0,0.
        CellDetailArray.SetValue("pmx150_01", 0, 0);
        Console.WriteLine("Cell Identifier   {0}", CellDetailArray.GetValue(0, 0));


        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but it may help:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter values for Cell ID, Sample, Write/TX, Depass, Discharge Date and Discharge load.");
    String[,] CellDetailArray = new String[16, 6];

    for (int i = 0; i < CellDetailArray.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Data for row no. {0}:", i + 1));
        for (int j = 0; j < CellDetailArray.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            Console.Write(string.Format("\tValue for column no. {0}: ", j + 1));
            CellDetailArray[i, j] = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Data entry finished.\n\nArray contents:");

    for (int i = 0; i < CellDetailArray.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        Console.Write(string.Format("\nRow no. {0}: ", i + 1));
        for (int j = 0; j < CellDetailArray.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            Console.Write(string.Format("\"{0}\"", CellDetailArray[i, j]));
            if (j < CellDetailArray.GetLength(1) - 1)
                Console.Write(", ");
        }
    }
}
```

Note: you say your array must be 7x16, but you only list 6 fields, so I made the array 6x16 (16 rows with 6 fields).

Comment: excellent Andrew, reading msdn links and RTFM'ing as much as i can on this, i will run this code and understand what is happening in it, i may have more fields to put in, got so confused i forgot what entry is columns and what is rows too! love loops in loops,, steve

Comment: used the code you gave me, i now understand far more on how this works, thank you very much, i have modified it to include the necessary headers for easier input and output, much appreciated Andrew,

Answer (score 0):

and here is my code, thanks Andrew,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Input_Cell_details_to_Array

{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //string[] CellDataHeaders = new string[7] { "CellID", "Sample", "WriteTX", "Depass", "DischargeDate", "Discharge" };
            Console.WriteLine("Enter values for Cell ID (CellType_Serial_LoadType_Term), Sample, Write/TX, Depass, Discharge Date (dd/mm/yyyy) and Discharge load.");
            String[,] CellDetailArray = new String[16, 7];

            for (int i = 0; i < CellDetailArray.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                string[] CellDataHeaders = new string[7] { "Cell ID", "Quiescent", "Sample", "WriteTX", "Depass", "DischargeDate", "Discharge" };
                Console.WriteLine("####################################################################################################");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Data for row no. {0}:", i + 1));

                for (int j = 0; j < CellDetailArray.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(CellDataHeaders[j]);
                    Console.Write(string.Format("\tValue for column no. {0}: ", j + 1));
                    CellDetailArray[i, j] = Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("========================================================================================================");
            Console.WriteLine("Data entry finished.\n\n Cell Detail Array contents:");

            for (int i = 0; i < CellDetailArray.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                Console.Write(string.Format("\nRow no. {0}: ", i + 1));
                for (int j = 0; j < CellDetailArray.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(string.Format("\"{0}\"", CellDetailArray[i, j]));
                    if (j < CellDetailArray.GetLength(1) - 1)
                        Console.Write(", ");
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! A few comments:
1) Place `CellDataHeaders` where you commented it. It's an array that has a meaning for the whole program, so it shouldn't be declared inside a loop. You are declaring 16 `string` arrays this way. 2) Now that you have the field name, you don't need to display the column number. The field name is much better. 3) You can use `ReadKey()` instead of `ReadLine()` so any key unpauses the program instead of just `<Enter>`. 4) Use the "Code Sample" ("{}", Ctrl+K) option in the editor when including C# code. The snippet option you used is only for HTML, Javascript and CSS.

Comment: ok i will study those points and make the changes,,, thanks again andrew,

Comment: It was a pleasure. :)